# "ERROR: py37: InterpreterNotFound: python3.7" when running tox from github

Tags: github, python-3.7, github-actions, tox

I have a project on GitHub with a tox.ini file:

```
[tox]
envlist = py3

[testenv]
deps = -rrequirements.txt
commands =
    pytest --doctest-modules
```

It works well. But when I replace "py3" with "py37", it fails with the error:

```
ERROR:  py37: InterpreterNotFound: python3.7
```

As far as I know, tox should support Python 3.7. Is this a problem specifically with tox on github?

Comment: Is Python 3.7 installed on the machine? Is it accessible, for example as `python3.7` on the command line?

Comment: @sinoroc The project is on GitHub, and tox is run by "GitHub actions", so it is not my machine. How can I check if python3.7 is installed on their machine?

Comment: I see, it wasn't clear from the question. I'm not familiar with _Github actions_. But I guess a good first step would be to show the _github actions_ configuration (the workflows?), so that users familiar with it can help sort it out.

Comment: You can check here for software installed on the runners https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/software-installed-on-github-hosted-runners. Using https://github.com/actions/setup-python will probably fix your problem.

Comment: @riQQ thanks! this seems helpful, but how can I know which version of Ubuntu is used?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi are you using `ubuntu-latest`? "The ubuntu-latest YAML workflow label still uses the Ubuntu 18.04 virtual environment."

Answer (score 17):

In the tox.ini file, write `python3.7` instead of `py37` and you will see that it works.

All credits to the Github user [glinskyc](https://github.com/glinskyc) for his [thread](https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues/378#issuecomment-413937359) on Github issues.

Also make sure that you are using the latest version for **tox**, that is `3.23.1`

Comment: I just tried this myself. It *seemed* to work, but then I noticed it runs everything with the default Python (3.9 in my case)! I get messages with paths like `/[pathredacted]/.tox/python3.7/lib/python3.9/site-packages/` in them ("python3.7" is the tox environment, and "python3.9" is the Python installed into it). I won't say it *never* works, but it apparently doesn't work on Linux with tox 3.24.3.

Comment: July 2022 I still receive the issue pointed out By Tim Pederick, also on Ubuntu 22.04, and now my code is breaking because it is running Python3.10 even though tox says it's running Python3.9

Comment: @TimPederick is right, this is just using the most recent available python and not the specified one.  You can change it to something crazy like `python9000` and it'll still just "work" because that's not a predefined tag like `py37` is.

Comment: Double confirmed: using `python3.7` will **not** fail where it is supposed to fail (on things like forgetting `from __future__ import annotations` when using type hints), while `py37` fails as expected.

Answer (score 0):

From a combination of the answers and resources provided here. What I did was:

- through `pyenv` I did install all python version I needed.
- I did symlinked all of them in a bin folder which was already in my PATH. Symlinks already were named the same as tox was expecting: python3.7, python3.8 and pypy3
- no renaming in tox was required